# Python Lambda function can't execute HTTPS cURL command

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, curl, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function which is defined by the following simple script which directs my EC2 instance to perform a backup:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    import subprocess
    result = subprocess.call("curl -k https://loadbalancer.stuff.domain.com/backup/", shell=True)
    return result
```

I have run the shell command in the subprocess above from 2 separate servers and it works fine on those, however I get a return error code of 6 when done from Lambda which means:

> CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST (6):
>   Couldn't resolve host. The given remote host was not resolved.

I have no idea how to proceed, and I've tried literally every single other way of performing this HTTPS request. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is a link to the load balancer correct "loadbalancer.stuff.domain.com"?

Comment: Correct. It could be replaced with an EC2 instance IP if you wanted: 
> ##.##.###:###/backup/ or whatever

Comment: Does your EC2 instance and Load Balancer security group has HTTPS port 443 open to public?

Comment: Yep: HTTPS
TCP
443
0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Is the Lambda function running inside a VPC?

Comment: Nope: VPC - No VPC

Comment: This may be a silly question but have you tried with a hard coded IP address to bypass the DNS lookup?

Comment: Just tried all forms of the ip address, and they all cause a timeout (60 seconds) instead of a cURL error.

Comment: What happened if you run http instead of https?

Comment: That results in another timeout.

Comment: Is your Load balancer in a VPC? If so, is it publicly accessible? eg. can you do `curl -k https://loadbalancer.stuff.domain.com/backup` from outside your VPC?

Comment: Ah I cannot do it from outside the VPC. So I'm assuming I have to find some way to allow the Lambda instance to access the VPC.

Comment: @EschersEnigma yes that's kind of an important detail. You will need to place the Lambda function within your VPC.

Answer (score 1):

Your Lambda function is executing outside of your VPC.

But your load balancer is inside your VPC, and not publicly accessible. So the Lambda function does not have a network path to the load balancer.

There are 2 possible resolutions:

1. Put your Lambda function inside your VPC, or
2. Make your load balancer public.

Comment: There's a third resolution where I add lambda to my IAM role with the AWS VPC role attached, and feed the VPC ID,  subnet IDs, and security group ID into the lambda function create with that IAM role specified.

Comment: @EschersEnigma your "third resolution" would only give the Lambda function access to make modifications to the VPC. In order to communicate with a server in the VPC it still has to be running within the VPC network, and the IAM role has nothing to do with that.

Comment: What do you mean by create it within the VPC

Comment: In the UI when you create a Lambda function, you have the option of placing it within the VPC.